# jasmine 2.0, requirejs, testr - just a blank page with no errors

Tags: javascript, testing, requirejs, jasmine, testr

It seems that there are a number of posts grappling with Jasmine 1.3 and Requirejs, but I'm having trouble with 2.0. I am using Jasmine 2.0 for tests, requirejs for AMD compliance and testr to mock some of my modules in my tests.

When I open the page, however, it's blank with nothing in the console.

You can see the project in full at https://github.com/nopwd/client if that's more helpful.

I have a test.html page set up:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>NoPwd Testing Rig</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="lib/testr.js/testr.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            testr.config({
                root: './',
                baseUrl: './',
                ignore: ['lodash']
            });

            testr.run('test.js', function() {});
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have a test.js file which is the entry point:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // ...
    },
    shim: {
        'jasmine/jasmine': {
            exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
        },
        'jasmine/jasmine-html': {
            deps: ['jasmine/jasmine'],
            exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
        },
        'jasmine/boot': {
            deps: ['jasmine/jasmine', 'jasmine/jasmine-html'],
            exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
        },
        'jasmine-ajax': {
            deps: ['jasmine/jasmine', 'jasmine/boot'],
            exports: 'window.jasmineRequire'
        }
    }
});

require(
    [
        'jasmine/jasmine-html', 'jasmine/boot', 'jasmine-ajax',
        'spec/nopwd-spec', 'spec/hash-spec', 'spec/transport-spec'
    ],
    function() {
        'use strict';
    }
);
```

I know for previous Jasmine versions you'd have to call `jasmine.getEnv().execute()` but it doesn't seem to be the case with 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the problem is that jasmine attaches itself to `window.onload()`. Now since `require()` has been called, `window.onload()` is already used, and so the handlers never get called. The answer, I found, is to call `window.onload()` manually inside the entry point (for me: `test.js`).

There's a good example [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/jasmine-js/requirejs%7Csort%3adate/jasmine-js/SgjHOUoFG58/HdGG8UwRiZsJ).